# SSIS - Pass variable in OleDB Command (Row Sampling to Update Existing Row)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sampling, oledbcommand

In OleDB command, how to pass the variable to update the table?

I wanna use SSIS to load big volume of testing data, the file name and code are unique, but the other details could be repetitive (so I use row sampling to get the sample data).

Table: MasterFile

Columns: Name, Code, Reftag, AdminGroup, OrgUnits...

1. As shown in control flow below, LoadNewMasterFile data flow will load the Name and Code to MasterFile table, which is unique
2. Execute SQL task will get the Name and Code from the Master File and store as variable with script task.
3. ForEachContainer will loop each code.
4. Data Flow Task 1 is the one with Row Sampling, aim to retrieve one sample row and update column Reftag, AdminGroup, OrgUnits...

Control Flow screenshot
[image]

In OleDB command, how to pass the variable to update the table?
[image]
[image]

Comment: A few things you should understand: 1. To pass an SSIS variable into an OLE DB command, you need to use a parameter placeholder (a `?` in your SQL statement) then map the SSIS variable to your placeholder. 2. Using row by row updates in an OLE DB command is slow and not really scaleable. In my opinion, using an ELT approach is faster and less convoluted. An ELT approach is where you stage the data into tables then run SQL on the tables inside the database. All your logic goes into that SQL, and everything runs much faster because it is set based.

Comment: In other words, in your SQL code, replace `@[User::RefCode]` with `?`, then in your task, map `@[User::RefCode]` through in the parameters section.

Comment: As @Nick.McDermaid points out you need every variable to be with ? and then in the correct order

Comment: You've posted a screenshot of the advanced editor.   You get to the parameters from the basic properties dialog box.   If you still have trouble, post a screenshot of the parameters tab from that box.